# Retrieving hidden variable value in Controller Error using "multipart/form-data" to upload file

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

Well my task is to upload a file when and there two application (app) which have to different type of upload one app is called APA and other is fSCG. When i remove if APA else SCG the code works if I use if APA else SCG i get null error. Please see the below code

In my JSP the code is below --

```
<form name="upload" action="/call" enctype= "multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    Select file: <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="app" value="${app}"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

this is the java controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/call", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    final String app = request.getParameter("app");
    **if (app.equals(APA) {**  This is where the error is 


        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
         response.setContentType("text/html");
          java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter( );

        if (!isMultipart) {

             return;

        }
         out.println("<h2> File is successfully uploaded<h2>"); 
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        try {
            // Parse the request
            List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator iter = items.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                    String uploadFolder = "C:\\Users;
                    String filePath = uploadFolder + File.separator + fileName;
                    File uploadedFile = new File(filePath);

                    item.write(uploadedFile);

                }
            }

        } catch (FileUploadException ex) {
            throw new ServletException(ex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new ServletException(ex);
        }
    }

else if
```

if (app.equals(SCG)) {**  Error here
code to upload almost same as above
}

Why i cant upload with if app please suggest me something possible give the example

Comment: Don't use this old school way of doing file upload. Spring has annotation for this purpose.

Comment: Can you add annotation into existing code well i dont know much about spring and this is urgent work

Comment: Google `spring upload file`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access uploaded file in Spring, you have to add the following field in your MVC configuration file (aka `bean.xml`):

```
<!-- Multipart resolver to be used for file uploading mechanisms -->
<bean name="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000"/>
</bean>
```

Then you can access contents and metadata of uploaded file in your `Controller` class as:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "register")
public void register(MultipartFile uploadedFile){
    System.out.println(uploadedFile.getContentType());
    System.out.println(uploadedFile.getOriginalFileName());
    System.out.println(uploadedFile.getSize());

    byte[] fileContents = uploadedFile.getBytes();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "register")
public void register(@RequestParam(value="file") MultipartFile   uploadedFile,@RequestParam(value="app")String app){
    System.out.println(uploadedFile.getContentType());
    System.out.println(uploadedFile.getOriginalFileName());
    System.out.println(uploadedFile.getSize());
}
```